# Why is foldl1' not generalized to Foldable?

Tags: haskell, typeclass, fold

The title says it all. `foldl1` and `foldl'` are both generalized to `Foldable`, while `foldl1'` is not. Is this just a recent oversight? Or is it a design choice?

The type of [`foldl1'`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:foldl1-39-) is

```
foldl1' :: (a -> a -> a) -> [a] -> a
```

I expected it to have the same type as `foldl1`:

```
foldl1 :: Foldable t => (a -> a -> a) -> t a -> a
```

I also see that `foldl1'` is exported by [`Data.List`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:foldl1-39-) but not [`Data.Foldable`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v:foldl-39-). Perhaps this is related?

Comment: Neither `foldl1` nor `foldl1'` belongs in `Foldable`. They belong in `Foldable1`, the class of nonempty foldable containers. Someone made a mistake and put `foldl1` in `Foldable`. I don't think anyone has the heart to compound that error.

Comment: @dfeuer: was the introduction of `Foldable` not preceded by a _really_ long period of discussion and polls? Was this overlooked or is it some compromise?

Comment: @ljedrz I think you're mixing up the discussion about using `Foldable` in the Prelude with the original design (if any) of `Foldable`.

Comment: @Cactus: I thought this was a parallel discussion, but you're right - I can't seem to be able to find anything on `Foldable` that was not related to `Prelude`.

Comment: @ljedrz `Foldable` has existed in its current form for ages.

Comment: I reckon there was so much discussion about the FTP that any argument about the `fold*1*` variants likely got drowned in noise.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the generalized form just [would have no good place to live](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Prelude710/FTP#SomefunctionsinData.ListcouldbegeneralizedtoFoldablebuthavenotbeen.ForexampleisPrefixOfandisInfixOfcanbegeneralised.Moregenerallyanythingwithalistinanargumentpositioncanbegeneralized.)? There may also have been some performance reasons behind this, but I couldn't find any information about it.

Comment: Data.List already exports the generalized form of foldl1 and foldl', both of which are part of the Foldable instance. So it seems like a generalized foldl1' should be exported from both Data.List and Data.Foldable for consistency sake.